Social login not working
I have installed the Mageplaza_SocialLogin module in Magento 2.4.6 for Google social login and configured it as well. However, when I try to use it on the frontend, it gives me a 403 Forbidden error. To check, I added a die() in the files, and when the callback URL is hit from Google Console, neither the Callback controller nor the index.php file is accessed. However, when I remove userinfo.profile from the callback URL, both the controller and the index.php file become accessible. Can someone tell me what the issue might be?
Please check the screenshots of the Google social login flow.




can you set the callback URL in google console? like..https://i.imgur.com/UDzhuFc.png

@KevalChauhan Yes, I have already added the redirect URL to Google Console.
